# Java Array.asList error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created an array list using asList() but I'm getting lot of errors

```
@Service
public class ArticleService {

List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>(Arrays.asList(
new Article( id:"1", name: "Article 01", description: "Description 01" ),
new Article( id:"2", name: "Article 02", description: "Description 02" ),
new Article( id:"3", name: "Article 03", description: "Description 03" )
));

public List<Article> getAllArticles(){
return articleList;
}
}
```

Comment: lots of error means what kind of error?

Comment: Please post any compiler errors, and also write a minimal and complete example.

Comment: Yeah... that's not Java. `new Article( id:"1", name: "Article 01", description: "Description 01" )`??? Maybe start by learning the basic syntax of the language.

Comment: I'm trying to upload an image but the app is crashing

Comment: Errors like <identifier> expected
';' expected Java illegal start of type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Article class is like below if not please make proper class,

```
class Article{
       String id;
       String article;
       String description;
   Article(String id ,String articleName,String description)
   {
      this.id=id;
      this.articleName = articleName;
      this.description = description;
   }
   ........
   //your getter/setters are defined here.

}
```

Now you should use them in your main class as below,

```
List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>(Arrays.asList(
                new Article( "1","Article 01", "Description 01" ),
                new Article( "2","Article 02","Description 02" ),
                new Article("3","Article 03","Description 03" )
                ));

 //this is the correct way of using it.
```

Answer (score 0):

correct way of using Arrays.asList:

```
List<Article> articleList = Arrays.asList(new Article(),new Article(),new Article());
```

Also you are not passing the arguments to the contractor correctly, if you have three strings then it should look like:

```
new Article("arg0","arg1","arg1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// you can execute your business logic like below code

List<Article> articleList=null;
        articleList = (List<Article>) new ArrayList();

        Article art = new Article();
        art.setId(0);
        art.setName("Article 01");
        art.setDescription("Description 01");
        articleList.add(art);
```